# How to make exim4 on Debian safe?

Tags: exim, smtp

I am running exim4 on a vanilla Debian Stable system. The machine has proper DNS A and MX records. I want to use it as a mail server.

SMTP with TLS already works fine for authenticated users.

However I can still telnet from somewhere else to the server using smtp and send mails to my own domain by spoofing the MAIL FROM and picking the right RCPT TO.

How can I configure exim so that only real mail hosts with MX record can use unauthenticated SMTP?

Comment: This sounds like a *really* bad idea, especially for mail from domains where the MX record points to an outsourced spam filter server (or even just a spam "firewall" appliance server), and some other server handles outgoing mail.  Or all mail from Gmail.

Comment: DerfK: can you elaborate on that? How else would you reject mails from spammers that use your own email addresses as from and rcpt?

Comment: Blocking mail forged from your own domain is one thing.  The assumption that "real mail hosts" are always in the MX server list is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279320/how-can-i-change-exim4-config-from-warn-on-no-reverse-dns-to-actively-rejecting) which sort of makes my configuration better. It changes the default warning on failed RDNS lookup to an error. Debian usually only warns on a failed reverse DNS lookup, if `CHECK_RCPT_REVERSE_DNS` is set. However, this piece of configuration will change that to an error:

```
# Verify reverse DNS lookup of the sender's host.
deny
  message Reverse DNS verification failed
  !verify = reverse_host_lookup
  !hosts = ${if exists{CONFDIR/local_broken_dns_whitelist}\
                      {CONFDIR/local_broken_dns_whitelist} {}}
```

It seems what I want in the end is [forward confirmed reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS).